# async not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, timeout, polymer

I have a polymer element which is grabbing data from a spreadsheet through "polymer-jsonp".
Once the data has arrived, I update the content of my element and want to get its displayed size.

I expect the async to be called when images and content has been fully rendered.
(http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#asyncmethod)

Calling refresh as below appears to return the size of my divs without the inner images.
    ...
    
    ...

```
researchChanged: function() {
        if(this.research){
          this.$.title.innerHTML = this.research.feed.entry[0].gsx$title.$t;

          // call refresh
          this.async(this.refresh);

        }
      }
```

Calling refresh with a delay appears to return the expected size.

```
this.async(function() {
                this.refresh();
              }, null, 10);
```

Is it the expected behavior?
Can we minimize this async delay somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `async` does is wait until JavaScript has yielded the thread. There is no guarantee that any particular other asynchronous task is done.

For example, whenever you create an `<img>` element, when that picture is fully loaded is indeterminate (because the browser may have to go the network to load the pixels). You have to listen to the element's `onload` event to know for sure.

Now, sometimes we talk about **microtasks**. The `async` method and microtasks go together. An easy way to think about a microtask is as everything that will get done before your `async` action happens.

For example, if you call `async` you can be assured that all data-propagations (due to bindings and observers) will occur before your async method executes. Mutation observers and pending events are also all resolved in a single microtask.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any of the polymer layouts?
In my case I had to listen to one of the layout events (polymer-layout, polymer-grid-layout) which fire when layout has finished